Slider no se pone uno al lado del otro utilizando forEach
El código forEach funciona y todos los divs se generan, pero al utilizar el append hace que se vayan uno abajo del otro y no al costado como yo deseo. Como podría corregirlo?
Adjunto el código, deseo que los divs salgan se muestren uno al lado del otro por favor


    leerHabitaciones();
        function leerHabitaciones(){
            //$.get, función en JQUERY que permite leer un JSON
            $.get("ServletHabitacionesJSON",function(response){
                //console.log(response);
                //bucle para realizar recorrido sobre response
                $.each(response,function(index,item){
                    $("#carrusel").append(`
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="habitaciones">
                                    <div class="habitacion">
                                        <h1 class="cursor-pointer" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalHotel">\${item.codigo}</h1>
                                        <p class="cursor-pointer" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalActualizarEstado">\${item.estado}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        `);
                })
                new DataTable("#carrusel");
            })
        }
        




Al presionar el botón "Ejecutar" se debe poder ver el comportamiento que describes, esto no sucede. Favor agregar el código necesario para para generar el [MCVE]

Además, no confundir slider con carrusel

¿Un DataTable con un carrusel? Extraño.
